# why APK file size downloaded from apkcombo.com larger than the original base.apk file (backup from my Android)?

Tags: apk

i installed application from Google Play and backup this application from my android phone as apk but when i got the same application and same version from apkcombo site i noticed the apk file was greater than my backup file.

could anybody explain it

Comment: If apps are uploaded to Google in AAB format, then you get not only `base.apk` but a lot of other split APK files that all together need to be installed. Most likely your exported base.apk is just an incomplete fraction of the app and the one from apkcombo.com is the full version. Without knowing the app this is just a guess.

Comment: thanks Robert. well, this is what i may have guessed too. But how can apkcombo get the full version? I also noticed a difference outputs  'aapt2 dump badging x.apk' for both applications, i see 'native-code: 'arm64-v8a' 'armeabi-v7a' 'x86' 'x86_64' , and I'm seeing "native code: 'arm64-v8a' 'armeabi-v7a' 'x86' 'x86_64' in favor of the apkcombo version.

What I'm curious about is how I can get the full version like apkcombo did!?